# What is the definition of a regular operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, definition, operator-algebras

If $T$ is a bounded linear operator on a normed space $X$, what does "$T$ is a regular operator" mean?

Comment: Did you *try* Googling this?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find any definition

Comment: Where did you see this term?

Comment: in some papers, but they don't mention its definition

Comment: Yes, which specific papers? Can you mention at least one?

Comment: for example the paper " On linear operators having supercyclic vectors" by Hezrog available online. P. 296 line 13 from down

Comment: In the context of linear operators, regular seems to mean invertible or bijective. Read the papers where you've seen this term and see if this definition makes sense.

Comment: I don't think it means invertible or bijective.

Answer (score 2):

One definition I saw was: $T$ is invertible and its inverse is also bounded. The reference is this paper
http://www.liusb.com/pdf/amm.pdf

Comment: Upvoting, to counteract the review comment. This provides (and already provided in its original form, before the edit) an answer to the question, very probably the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of vector lattices, an operator is called **regular** if it is the difference of two positive operators. In particular, if your normed space has a lattice structure, the definition applies.

Comment: I am reading Banach Lattice by Peter Mayer-Nieberg. While definitely it is not the answer op wants, you have helped me.

Answer (score 1):

In this paper https://ir.uiowa.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2479&context=etd,  I see (p.7)  a regular operator stated as a densely defined closed operator. (Rather confusingly it says "A is regular if $\mathscr D (A)$ is dense and it is closed"  - clearly the "closure" refers to the operator not the domain else it would just be a bounded operator).

Since it quotes regularity in some theorems of von Neumann (e.g. p.13) I'd assume it has credibility.